# Passing in Session data from Flask to WTForms

Tags: python, session, flask, wtforms

So I'm having issues with passing in a list from my Flask session object into the WTForms that I'm using. 
I'm trying to access the 'strategy' object (it's a list) within the session object.

The goal is to list all of the strategies that are associated with the current user.

Within the Flask app:

```
class Create_Indicator_Form(Form):
    security = TextField('Ticker Name', [
                         validators.Required(),
                         validators.Length(min=1, max=6)])
    mva_10 = BooleanField('10 day moving average')
    mva_25 = BooleanField('25 day moving average')
    strategy = SelectField('strategy', session['strategy'])
    def validate_mva_10(form, field):
        if form.mva_25.data is True and field.data is True:
            raise ValidationError('You can only choose one reference')
        if form.mva_25.data is False and field.data is False:
            raise ValidationError('You must choose at least one reference')

@app.route('/create_indicator', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_indicator():
    check_if_logged_in()
    f = request.form
    create_indicator_form = Create_Indicator_Form(f)
    if request.method == 'POST' and create_indicator_form.validate():
        indicator_id = get_next_index('indicator', 'indicator_id')
        ticker = create_indicator_form.security.data
        if create_indicator_form.mva_10.data is True:
            mva_10_day = 'Y'
            mva_25_day = 'N'
        else:
            mva_10_day = 'N'
            mva_25_day = 'Y'
        row = [indicator_id, ticker, mva_10_day, mva_25_day]
        add_data('indicator', row)
        # adding relation
        criteria_row = [session['strategy'][0], indicator_id]
        add_data('criteria', criteria_row)
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    create_indicator_form.strategies = session['strategy']
    return render_template('create_indicator.html',
                           form=create_indicator_form)
```

When I try to run the flask app I'm thrown this error:

```
RuntimeError: working outside of request context
```

with a trace back to where I access the session object in the Create_Indicator_Form class.

I've realized since starting to try to fix this that it'd be more efficient to chose between the mva_10 and mva_25 with a select field but I would like to resolve this issue before refactoring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Why

This is because the `strategy = SelectField('strategy', session['strategy'])` line is executed when the file is loaded, as it is part of the `Create_Indicator_Form` class definition.

At this time, you're indeed `working outside of request context`

## How to fix it

Using a class factory will work here:

```
def CreateIndicatorForm():

    class IndicatorForm(Form):
        security = TextField('Ticker Name', [
                             validators.Required(),
                             validators.Length(min=1, max=6)])
        mva_10 = BooleanField('10 day moving average')
        mva_25 = BooleanField('25 day moving average')
        strategy = SelectField('strategy', session['strategy'])
        def validate_mva_10(form, field):
            if form.mva_25.data is True and field.data is True:
                raise ValidationError('You can only choose one reference')
            if form.mva_25.data is False and field.data is False:
                raise ValidationError('You must choose at least one reference')

    return IndicatorForm
```

Be mindful that calling `CreateIndicatorForm()` returns a *Form class*, so to instantiate an actual form, you need to use: `CreateIndicatorForm()()` (i.e. "call" the class, like you would any other class to create a new instance).

When instantiating the form, you can (and should) pass arguments to the form constructor, such as the request data: `CreateIndicatorForm()(request.form)`.

---

Also, making `session['strategy']` an argument of the factory function would be better practice here - this would make the factory reusable outside of request context and would ensure you don't have to create a new form *class* for every single request.

Comment: I'm confused about how to call this method. This what I tried, but then the template could not detect the attributes of the form when it tried to render

indicator_form = CreateIndicatorForm();
create_indicator_form = indicator_form(request.form)

Comment: @Twigger Yeah, I didn't really do great with naming here. Do `indicator_form = CreateIndicatorForm()()`. You coudl also replace the method's last line with `return IndicatorForm()` and do `indicator_form = CreateIndicatorForm()`

Comment: It still throws the same error. It's not recognizing that security is an attribute of the form.

Comment: @Twigger What does type(indicator_form) return?

Comment: Type() returns <class '__main__.Create_Strategy_Form'>

Comment: So I still have some things to fix, but the issue was that the attributes weren't associated with the Form. http://pastie.org/7391083

Comment: @Twigger This is because in your return statement: you're not returning the correct class. You should `return Create_Indicator_Form(request.form)`, not `return Create_Strategy_Form(request.form)`.

Comment: Could you adjust the example to what you told Nate in the comments? I had trouble calling the function until I saw the problem was i had no brackets in the return, just like you in the example.

Comment: @TobiasKolb Thanks! I updated the response accordingly. However, I think the factory shouldn't return an instance, since that means you can't pass arguments to the form constructor, so I did reject your suggested edit.

Comment: thanks for the response. could you fix the indent on the def return in the last line please? would to it myself, but it's not enough chars for an edit.